# Oracle SQL, Having trouble getting LIKE to call a - character representing MiddleINIT

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to call the people without middle names and present in the table.  the middle names are represented as a - while others are actual letters.

I can get this work when I call
`WHERE Bowlersmiddleinit LIKE 'A'` and it brings up the table.

I just ca'nt seem to figure out how to call the Bowlersmiddleinit that don't actually have a middle name listed but are represented by `-`

```
SELECT Bowlermiddleinit, Bowlerlastname
FROM Bowlers
WHERE Bowlermiddleinit LIKE '-'
ORDER BY Bowlerlastname ASC;
```

Comment: That *should* work (although it is too complicated - why `LIKE` and not simply `=`?) Try something: `select max(length(bowlermiddleinit)) from bowlers` and see what it reports. (Also, are you sure there is at least one bolwer with `-` for `middleinit`?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: there is more than one bowler with no middleint And i thought the same to use '=' but the directions want to use 'LIKE'@mathguy

Comment: Directions? Is that some homework? And, did you run the little query I suggested, to see if perhaps you may have dash followed by space, or something like that, in the middleinit?

Comment: @mathguy yes it is literally my only question having trouble with and no I have not ran it yet doing now once my XenDesktop comes up.

Comment: Is that `-` really a dash in the field, or is it a way to represent `NULL` in your interface? Did you try `... where bowlermiddleinit is null`?

Comment: @mathguy it really is a `-` I thought i could use `NULL` as well but nothing. Everything I have put in there shows `no data found` or if i actual use a middleinit char like `A` it puts out the table.

Comment: Can you [`dump()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions063.htm#SQLRF00635) tthe column values you think are that character, and the one you are using in your query,  and see if they are actually the same? Maybe it's a different code point to what you are expecting and seacrhing for [but just looks similar](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm).

Comment: @Mathguy thanks I used `IS NULL` and it worked fine.  I don't know why he wanted me to use why but I explained it can't be possible `LIKE` because `null` is `null` don't think there is anything that could be `LIKE null` thanks again.